# Discrete math number problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would I justify the following statement.

Two integers are consecutive if and only if one is more than the other. Any product of four consecutive integers is one less than a perfect square.

I think this is true.

because for example

$2<3<4<5$

$2*4*5*3=120$

Which one less than 121 a perfect square.

So how would I justify it I did

Let n be a integer

$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)+1
=(m)^2$

But I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The RHS in the last equality shouldn't be $n$. Choose another symbol, for instance $m$. It shouldn't be $-1$ on the LHS, but rather $+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) &= n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n +1-1 \\
& = n^2\left(n^2+6n+11+\frac{6}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) -1 \\
& = n^2\left(\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+6\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)+11-2\right) -1 \\
& = n^2\left(\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+6\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)+9\right) -1 \\
& = n^2\left(n+\frac{1}{n}+3\right)^2-1 \\
& = \left(n^2+3n+1\right)^2-1 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: yes this make perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

Try to proceed heuristically: write down the numbers (possible squares) you get for the first few values of $n$. Write down the numbers they are the squares of. Try to find a relationship between this and $n$. Is the former a polynomial in $n$?
Develop the product $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$.

Found anything?